# Replicating a fantasy map coastline pattern along a path

Tags: inkscape, fill, maps

In fantasy maps coastlines are sometimes portrayed using a combination of two parallel lines and wave shapes on the seaside. I wish to replicate this behaviour for a custom coastline (a path) in Inkscape.

My initial attempt in emulating this was to trace a repeated double line & wave pattern along a path. Doing so however rotates the pattern along the path, where I'm looking for the waves to remain horizontal to the page.

How can I best approach this?

[image: Fantasy map with coast line]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree, for the double line I would use pattern along path.

For the waves, I would make an offset object of the coast line, fill it with some color, draw a couple waves of different length, and would use the spray tool (settings: without rotation or scaling, not spraying over transparent areas, not spraying over color boundaries) to put them into place.

As a preview how this could look (would need some tweaking and more careful spraying, this was a quick trial):

[image: fantasy coastline test]